# Exporting XY data to .shp and I lose my points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, export, xy

I have coordinates (sampling points) as part of a larger excel file that I am trying to convert to a .shp file to overlay on a map.  When I add them to Arc as XY data they display just fine, but when I export to .shp file I lose my points.  When I select zoom to layer it zooms way way way out and still displays nothing.  Any ideas about what might be going wrong?  I am using ArcMap 10.1

Comment: Please tell us about your process.  How are you exporting the points to a `.shp`?

Comment: Also, what version of Excel are you using? For me 2013 does some crazy things...

Answer (score 1):

ensure that none of your field names have spaces in them. I had similar problem and when I took out spaces it worked.

Comment: I have also found this to be a cause. I believe hyphens should also be avoided.